# I had a error msg while run the build.xml in eclipse

Tags: selenium

```
D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip>ant compile`
```

**Buildfile:** `D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build.xml`

```
setClasspath:

init:

clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build

compile:
     [echo] making directory...
    [mkdir] Created dir: D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build
     [echo] Classpath===: D:\MY FILES\Selenium\Jar files\junit-4.10.jar;D:\MY FI
     LES\Selenium\Jar files\jxl.jar;D:\MY FILES\Selenium\Jar files\reportng-1.1.2.jar
    ;D:\MY FILES\Selenium\Jar files\testng-6.0.1.jar
     [echo] compiling...
    [javac] D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build.xml:43: warning: 'includeant
    runtime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for re
    peatable builds
    [javac] Compiling 1 source file to D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build
    [javac] D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\src\MMTPack\TripClass.java:5: pack
    age com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import com.thoughtworks.selenium.DefaultSelenium;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\src\MMTPack\TripClass.java:6: pack
    age com.thoughtworks.selenium does not exist
    [javac] import com.thoughtworks.selenium.Selenium;
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac] D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\src\MMTPack\TripClass.java:22: can
    not find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class Selenium
    [javac] location: class MMTPack.TripClass
    [javac]     private static Selenium selenium;
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\src\MMTPack\TripClass.java:27: can
    not find symbol
    [javac] symbol  : class DefaultSelenium
    [javac] location: class MMTPack.TripClass
    [javac]     selenium = new DefaultSelenium("Localhost", 4444, "*iexplore", "
    http://www.makemytrip.com/");
    [javac]                    ^
    [javac] 4 errors
```

**BUILD FAILED**

```
D:\MY FILES\My project\MakeMyTrip\build.xml:43: Compile failed; see the compiler
  error output for details.

  Total time: 2 seconds
```

Comment: Yes i added the jar files.

Comment: Yes i added jar files.

Comment: Pls see my xml and tell what is wrong on that